# Pushwoosh Conditions (AND/OR)

Tags: cordova, pushwoosh

In sending a message through the Pushwoosh API, all my conditions have to be satisfied in order for my message to reach the participant.

if CONDITION1 and CONDITION2 and CONDITION3 ... are satisfied, send the message

What if I want to specify an 'OR' set.

if (CONDITION1 or CONDITION2 or CONDITION3) send the message...

Like this:

Site ID = 10 AND ( Businesses IN [2] OR Subscriptions IN ['contests'])

--- here is that segment of the request:

```
[conditions] => Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Site ID
            [1] => IN
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Subscriptions
            [1] => IN
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => contests
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Businesses
            [1] => IN
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

        )

)
```